# Crear botones verticales fijos de la A a la Z en una página

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Quiero realizar unos botones de manera vertical, que queden fijos a la izquierda de la página y que siempre estén visibles. **Lo botones son todo el abecedario** quedando por ejemplo así:

```
A
B
C
D
E
.
.
.
.
Y
Z
```

Sé que puede quedar muy largo en mi página, pero quizás le pueda poner una especie de barra o flechas (hacia arriba o hacia abajo) para acortar el abecedario y de esta manera se mueva haciendoles clic. 
Claro que no voy a poner uno por uno los botones hasta llegar a la "Z" (seria tedioso y mucho "código"), **la idea es hacer una especie de for para recorrer e ir poniendo en cada botón la letra**.

El funcionamiento del mismo es que luego cuando se hace clic en una letra, por ejemplo la "E", me tiene que llevar a donde este todo el contenido que empieza con dicha letra (en la página estoy mostrando diferentes palabras ordenadas alfabéticamente).

Me gustaría saber cómo podría realizar esto. En `CSS` hay que poner `position: fixed` y `display: block`, eso esta bien. El problema es que no sé como hacer la parte de crear estos botones desde `JavaScript` o `JQuery` con un `for` (**desde la A a la Z**) e ir creando los elementos (por ejemplo para una lista), algo como `<li><a href="#" Title="Ir a la A"><img src="boton.png"></a></li>`...
Espero me puedan dar una idea.

Comment: Encontré un ejemplo para generar el abecedario, espero te sirva. saludos
[LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/cnordv7d/)

Comment: Está muy bueno, sólo faltaría ponerlo fijo y a la izquierda. Cosa que desde ahí no pude lograrlo.

Answer (score 3):

Este ejemplo crea los elementos `<li>` de una lista `<ul>`. Si lo abres en el inspector verás que dentro de cada `<li>` hay un elemento `<a>` cuyo `href="#${letra}"`. O sea: tus fragmentos de contenido tendrán que llevar un `id` Por ejemplo lo de la letra **a** tendrá `id="a"`

```js
let abc = ""
for(let i=97; i <= 122; i++){
let letra = String.fromCharCode(i); 
abc+= `<li><a href="#${letra}">${letra}</a></li>`
}

alfabeto.innerHTML = abc;
```

```html
<ul id="alfabeto"></ul>
```

A continuación un ejemplo básico de como quedaría con los articulos que tienen un `id`

```js
let abc = "";//el alfabeto
let art = "";// los articulos

for(let i=97; i <= 122; i++){
let letra = String.fromCharCode(i); 
//crea los elementos li
abc+= `<li><a href="#${letra}">${letra}</a></li>`
//crea los articulos cun su id y un elemento a que apunta hacia arriba
art+= `<article id="${letra}">
       <p><a href="#arriba">${letra}${letra}${letra}${letra}</a></p>
       </article>`
}

alfabeto.innerHTML = abc;
articulos.innerHTML = art;
```

```css
#wrap{display:flex}
section article{padding:1em;display:block;height:10em}
```

```html
<a id="arriba"></a>
<div id="wrap">
<ul id="alfabeto"></ul>
<section id="articulos">
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Me ha servido, más que nada la primer parte (la del alfabeto). La parte en que agregas la de "articulos" estaría bien, pero a eso ya lo tengo armado y no quiero tocarlo. Aunque claro me faltaría la de moverme a el contenido que corresponde con la letra seleccionada. Debería manejarme con los mismos ID.

Comment: En este caso crearía un objeto de equivalencias algo así: `let equivalencias = {a:"el_id_para_a", b:"el_id_para_b",.....z:"el_id_para_z"}` y después al crear la variable `abc` haría algo así: `<li><a href="#${equivalencias[letra]}">${letra}</a></li>`

Comment: Perdón, de nuevo, no comprendo muy bien eso. En mi caso, todo el contenido que corresponde a la letra "A" tiene un `<h2>` como título y así con las demás letras. He puesto algo como `<h2 id="a">` para llevarlo ahí cuando se haga clic en el link. El problema es que no me funciona. Es que todos esos `<h2>` con las demás palabras, las creo desde una página **php**.
Pero mis listas (`<li>`) de letras están en una página **.html** que por medio de `Jquery` (allí hago el for para las letras) y `Ajax` llamó a la página de **php**. ¿Cómo podría hacer que funcionen los clics en cada letra?

Comment: ¿puedes crear un codepen con una versión simplificada de lo que tienes?

Comment: Ok, voy a ver si puedo armar algo ahí. El tema es que el trabajo mayor esta en php y claro está en codepan no se puede hacer.

Comment: Ahí cree algo pequeño código para que veas: [Enlace](https://codepen.io/DamianMDQ/pen/wbgBbx), cuando entres, allí en los comentarios tienes un poco más de la explicación de lo que no me funciona y de lo que necesito hacer.

Comment: "Acá lo hace bien porque lo puse a mano en HTML. Pero al estar realizado, todo el contenido, desde PHP no me funciona" Esto quiere decir que el problema que tienes es en el código PHP y no en el javascript. Para lo demás que dices que quieres esto daría para varias preguntas aquí en el Stack Overflow

Comment: Entiendo, voy a tratar de armar otra pregunta para poner sobre la ubicación de ese div fijo al pie de la página y que tenga un botón de ocultar y mostrar. Mientras veré si puedo solucionar lo de PHP (que es lo fundamental).

Comment: Si estás a punto de reescribir el código PHP no estaría de menos poner el `<h2>` junto a todos los `<a class="GloIT"` correspondientes a la letra en un `<article>` o `<div>`. Esto te facilitaría mucho las cosas con el css y con el javascript

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93676/discussion-between-damian-garcia-and-enxaneta).